# How to modify a gzip compressed file

Tags: linux, file, gzip, compression

i've a single gzip compressed file (100GB uncompressed 40GB compressed). Now i would like to modify some bytes / ranges of bytes - i DO NOT want to change the files size.

For example
Bytes 8 + 10 and Bytes 5000 - 40000

is this possible without recompressing the whole file?

Stefan

Comment: You want to change the *original* file, right? Not the compressed file?

Comment: correct. The result would also affect the compressed one. But the data i know has to be applied on top of the original file. Imagine something like a diff to the original file. But it take too much time to decompress 100GB, then apply the diff and then recompress nearly the same data (diff changes just around 1-5% of the file).

Comment: @disaster123 I have a feeling you already know this won't work, even in theory. Any compression method will produce radically different output for any variation in input.

Comment: You can only do it by uncompressing, modifying, and recompressing.  Changing even one byte changes everything else that comes after.

Comment: @AndyLester, it changes what becomes before, too, potentially. This isn't run-length encoding. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.  It would be necessary to replace one or more deflate blocks with new blocks with exactly the same total number of bits, but with different contents.  If the new data is less compressible with deflate, this becomes impossible.  Even if it is more compressible, it would require a lot of bit twiddling by hand to try to get the bits to match.  And it still might not be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you want to change the file sizes makes no difference (since the resulting gzip isn't laid out according to the original file sizes anyway), but if you split the compressed file into parts so that the parts you want to modify are in isolated chunks, and use a multiple-file compression method instead of the single-file gzip method, you could update just the changed files without decompressing and compressing the entire file.

In your example:

```
bytes1-7.bin        \
bytes8-10.bin        \ bytes.zip
bytes11-4999.bin     /
bytes5000-40000.bin /
```

Then you could update `bytes8-10.bin` and `bytes5000-40000.bin` but not the other two. But whether this will take less time is dubious.

Answer (score -1):

The man page for gzip says "If you wish to create a single archive file with multiple members so that members can later be extracted independently, use an archiver such as tar or zip." I believe that means that gzip compression continues through the files, therefore is context-sensitive, and therefore will not permit what you want.

Either decompress/patch/recompress, or switch to a different representation of your data (perhaps an uncompressed tar or zip of individually compressed files, so you only have to decompress/recompress the one you want to change.) The latter will not store your data as compactly, in general, but that's the tradeoff you have to make.

Comment: That quote from the man page is about the ability to store *multiple  files* within the *same archive*, and being able to decompress only one or some of them, not about recompressibility or the specifics of this question. If this were tar or zip, the answer would be the same; modifying the compressed stream isn't possible.

Comment: Tar does not compress; modifying a tar archive *is* possible.
Zip, I believe, compresses on a per-file basis (or can be configured to do so), which also permits individual file extraction/replacement. The question was whether gzip offered the latter option, and I'm citing the man page as a strong indication that it does *not* do so. Hence, the proposal bzim proposed of separating compression and archiving, which would work with these other formats, will _not_ work with gzip. I stand by my answer.